# In a TFS server using git, how do I effectively merge changes across branches?

Tags: git, tfs

I apologize if this question is a little vague, but I'm not sure how else to ask it.

We have a TFS server that's using git as the underlying source control. We have a develop branch that people check code into for the current iteration. Then when we're about to do a release, we branch off of develop. From that point forward, when people make a check in to the release branch, they're cherry picking it to the develop branch...sometimes anyway.

The problem is that when I do a final merge from the release back to develop, it still shows all the changes that have already been cherry-picked, because apparently TFS is too dumb to actually look at the git branch differences. Instead, it's just showing the change history based on each work item. Even if the branches in git are identical because every change has already been cherry-picked, it still shows them as new changes in TFS.

This means that for every release, I have to do a git merge locally to see if there are any differences (there always are because somebody always forgets to cherry-pick something). Then I have to go through them all and verify that they're ok before doing a pull request in TFS, which is a huge pain. Furthermore, I also have to turn off the force-merge branch policy. Otherwise it bundles everything together and the change history still doesn't get merged. It gets even more complicated if there's more than one release branch at the same time.

Is there a better process where TFS will recognize that the changes from a cherry-pick are basically the same as the changes from the original check in and update the history that way?

Or something completely different. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why are you cherry picking the changes rather than merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cherry-pick a commit, the new version of it receives a new commit ID. Later when you merge, git sees two different commit IDs and therefore assumes they are two different sets of changes. Since it can't decide which set of changes to apply, you get a conflict that needs to be manually resolved - even though it's the exact same set of changes. For reasons of speed efficiency, git isn't doing actual file comparisons - it uses the commit ID to determine if changes have been applied.

In short, the way to avoid this is to not cherry-pick but merge - then the same commit ID is in both branches and git recognizes the changes are applied.

---

Personally, I really like the process described by [GitFlow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), but from what you mention of your process I *think* you just need to switch from cherry-picking to merging from release -> develop.

So, your team would:

1. Make a commit into `release`
2. Move the change back to develop with `git merge`
3. Repeat

Since the commit ID will be the same between branches, each merge operation will only apply the changes that have not already been applied to `develop`. So, even if something has been modified in `develop`, you will only get a conflict if it was also recently modified in `release`.

---

Since you mention people are not comfortable (potentially) merging other people's commits when syncing release to develop, the following process will avoid that issue:

1. Treat `release` like `master` and `develop` - IE no direct commits allowed
2. When a developer needs to start work, make a "feature" branch from `release`
3. After development is complete (and review, if applicable), merge the change from the "feature" into `release`
4. Then do a second merge from the "feature" into `develop`

Now, `release` and `develop` will have the same changes and each developer will only be responsible for their own conflicts.

NOTE: This results in many additional merge commits, and these WILL show up when you merge `release` into `develop`. However since the merge commits from `release` should be empty changes, I expect conflicts to be almost non-existent. Additionally, the git history will become very tangled. Personally, I don't consider that a problem and the rebase process you'd need to use to avoid it has its own learning curve.

Comment: That's a process I suggested to the team, and there are two ways to do this. One is to have everybody always immediately merge from release into develop immediately after making a check in to release. The problem with this is that two people often make a check in within a short timespan, and then when one of them tries to merge, it shows both people's changes. A lot of people are not comfortable with that. The second option is to only merge when the release is done, but then there are always a ton of conflicts because people have been continuing work on develop.

Comment: @mrplainswalker I have edited the answer to include a process that avoids the issue you mention. It's more overhead (of course), but there's always a trade-off